# How do i use Spring JPA repository to correctly save an object with a foreign key?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

i'm working on a project with both Hibernate and Spring for the first time. i've chosen to use uni-directional mapping, and it was working out pretty well exept for one thing. Whenever i try to save an Event with an EventType object in it. it gives me the following error:
`java.sql.SQLException: Field 'type_id' doesn't have a default value`

i'm using the standard JPA repository function `evenementRepository.save(evenement);`

## Here is what my database looks like:

[image]

## this is my Event class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "evenement")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Evenement {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String naam;

    private Date datum;

    private String status;

    private String beschrijving;

    private String locatie;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "evenement_ibfk_3"))
    private Evenement_Type eventType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "template_id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "evenement_ibfk_2"))
    private Template template;
//getters and setters
```

## this is my Event_Type class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "evenement_type")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Evenement_Type {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String naam;

    private String beschrijving;
//getters and setters
```

## controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EvenementController {

    @Autowired
    EvenementDAO evenementDAO;

    @PostMapping("/evenement")
    public Evenement createEvenement(@Valid @RequestBody Evenement evenement) {
            return evenementDAO.save(evenement);
    }
```

## dao

as you can see i double check if the event has an actual event_type, and if the event_type has an ID.
i'm 100% sure that is not the problem. it always has an output in the console.

```
@Service
public class EvenementDAO {
    @Autowired
    EvenementRepository evenementRepository;
    @Autowired
    Template_TaakDAO template_taakDAO = new Template_TaakDAO();
    @Autowired
    TaakDAO taakDAO = new TaakDAO();

    public Evenement save(Evenement evenement) {
        System.out.println(evenement.getEventType().getId());
        return evenementRepository.save(evenement);
    }
```

## JSON object send through postman

```
{
    "naam": "test-name",
    "datum": "2021-08-08",
    "status": "test-status",
    "beschrijving": "test-description",
    "locatie": "test-location",
    "eventType": {
        "id": 1,
        "naam": "test-name",
        "beschrijving": "test-description"
    },
    "template": null
}
```

there is one other class that uses Event_Type as a foreign key which also doesn't work.
all the other classes with foreign keys i have no problem with saving.
i'm pretty sure it is either the mapping or something in my database but i can't figure out what.
i'm sorry a lot of my code is in my native language, it's a really bad habit(all you need to know is that evenement means event).

please help, i've been stuck for ages.
if i forgot to post any important info please say so.

Answer (score 0):

Exception says that you are trying to save NULL in 'type_id' field, but you have non-null constraint in db and no default value.

Please take a look at this part:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "evenement_ibfk_3"))
    private Evenement_Type eventType;
```

You have defined the mapping on **type_id** field, but it is not mapped in target entity model. You should add it to Evenement model and populate in existing DB records to fix the problem.

Comment: I fixed it by removing ```insertable = false, updatable = false```. I have no idea why but it works. thanks for help though :  )